# Bootstrap SmartAdmin disable SmartForm validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, smartadmin

I'm working in a project built over the [SmartAdmin bootstrap webapp](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-WB0573SK0) that comes with some kind of form validation in a feature called [SmartForm](http://data.edwardsaquifer.org/form-elements.php). I don't know what it uses behind the scenes to validate the forms(it acts like jquery validator), but it is boring me with undesired behaviour.

I want to know how do I disable it.

The documentation doesn't helps. Its uselss to link it here because of the on-line version is not complete, you get it when you buy and download the full *application*.

As an example of what is happening, consider the following form element(that is generated by ASP.Net MVC 4 with its Data Annotations):

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="The field must have maximun of 100 characters." data-val-length-max="100" id="Company" name="Company" type="text" value="" class="valid">
```

As you can see it haves only a *max-length* validation, but its being treated as required by this validation tool. It marks it as required(red borders and background) and prevents the form to be submitted.

[image: Dev Tools Screenshot for Example]

I just want to disable it to keep handling the validation with jQuery Validator by itself.

**UPDATE**

Here is the - almost - full form dom, as requested in the comments:

[image]

Comment: can attach full form screenshot?

Comment: @SizS sorry for the delay, I was afk. Please check if the new image is enough.